# VBA: Change Colour of Textbox with Clickbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a checkbox on Sheet A and a textbox on Sheet B. I am trying to change the colour of the textbox on Sheet B (which is hidden), when the checkbox is checked.

I keep getting the '438' - 'Object does not support this property or method' error, but can't work out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

The code currently being used:

```
     Private Sub CheckBox8_Click()

    If CheckBox8 = True Then

       Sheets("Week_3").Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox10")).Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
       End With

    Else

         Sheets("Week_3").Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox10")).Select
         With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

    End If

    End Sub
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the colour changing sections to:

```
 With Sheets("Week_3").Shapes("TextBox 10").Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

The following section is not required:

```
Sheets("Week_3").Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox10")).Select
```